# how to limit number of rows and columns in a page

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have used matrix to display data. Now i want to limit the number of rows and columns display in a page. I have tried Ceiling(Fields!RowNumber(Nothing)/20) but then only one column will be displayed with 20 rows. I want 5 columns and 10 rows in each page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem and finally found the answer(s) here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx

Also here is another link to this issue:

http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/8/17/repeating-column-headings-other-advanced-tablix-member-prope.html

It is not very clear, but after you click on advanced mode make sure to hightlight STATIC under the "Row Groups" section then change the properties prvided.

Again not sure this is what you want exactly but I think  its worth a look.